Spark fails with error: Line Separator not in initial block of partition
I am running Spark jobs on Azure Synapse Analytics. The notebook reads and writes data from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 account (same storage, however, read and write happens at different paths). It processes CSV data (large chunk) and small reference data (parquet/CSV) and writes final output in parquet format. The larger dataset of CSV format is stored as 200 partition files.
The notebook job is using 980 vCores of Spark compute cluster (each node has 4 vCores and 28 GB memory). Overall following code logic is applied:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",200)

// Read the data from ADLS Gen2

// Do computations

// Write output
df = (outputDf
    .repartition(980)
    .write
    .mode("overwrite")
    .parquet(outputPath))

The executor error logs indicate following error:
2024-12-13 04:29:22,453 WARN TaskSetManager [task-result-getter-3]: Lost task 998.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 5210) (vm-d8e97779 executor 118): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Encountered error while reading file abfss://<endpointWithPath>?version=1733996160491?flength=8008249846. Details:
  at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFilesError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:877)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:353)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:158)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:764)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
  at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:574)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:577)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
  Suppressed: org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: null

Previous exception in task: Encountered error while reading file abfss://<endpointWithPath>?version=1733996160491?flength=8008249846. Details:
  org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFilesError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:877)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:353)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:158)
  scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.hashAgg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:764)
  scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
  org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
  org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
  org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:101)
  org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
  org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
  org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
  org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:574)
  org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
  org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:577)
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeTaskCompletionListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:172)
    ... 7 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.com.microsoft.vegas.common.VegasPipeInputStream.close(VegasPipeInputStream.java:806)
      at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:180)
      at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.close(LineReader.java:152)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.close(LineRecordReader.java:281)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.close(RecordReaderIterator.scala:69)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.close(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:71)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.$anonfun$readFile$2(CSVDataSource.scala:97)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.TextInputCSVDataSource$.$anonfun$readFile$2$adapted(CSVDataSource.scala:97)
      at org.apache.spark.TaskContext$$anon$1.onTaskCompletion(TaskContext.scala:132)
      at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.$anonfun$invokeTaskCompletionListeners$1(TaskContextImpl.scala:144)
      at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.$anonfun$invokeTaskCompletionListeners$1$adapted(TaskContextImpl.scala:144)
      at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:199)
      ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not open pipe [/mnt/vegas/pipes/2575cfd8-c0e5-43d6-b86d-21f829a05087.pipe, pos=0,blocksRead=0; bytesRead=0; availInPipe=0]
Vegas Service: Context=c18dceff-0a3e-4be0-9dfa-81200dbe71ce, Temporarily Unsupported Scenario: Line Separator not in initial block of partition
  at org.apache.hadoop.shaded.com.microsoft.vegas.common.VegasPipeInputStream.pipelineThread(VegasPipeInputStream.java:536)
  ... 3 more

I would like to understand the root cause of this issue. Because often retries or changing spark pool helps, and business logic works fine. However, intermittently these errors keep coming and notebook does not finish successfully in those cases.

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 800)
can you try the above

It seems the error results from reading the CSVs. So it would be helpful to see the read command.


Caused by: java.io.IOException:

Java IOExceptions are Input/Output (I/O) exceptions that occur when an input or output operation fails or is interrupted. For instance, attempting to read a file that does not exist would result in an I/O exception being thrown by Java.
ERROR:

Could not open pipe
[/mnt/vegas/pipes/2575cfd8-c0e5-43d6-b86d-21f829a05087.pipe,
pos=0,blocksRead=0; bytesRead=0; availInPipe=0] Vegas Service:
Context=c18dceff-0a3e-4be0-9dfa-81200dbe71ce, Temporarily Unsupported
Scenario: Line Separator not in initial block of partition at
org.apache.hadoop.shaded.com.microsoft.vegas.common.VegasPipeInputStream.pipelineThread(VegasPipeInputStream.java:536)

In the above ERROR (Could not open pipe... Temporarily Unsupported Scenario: Line Separator not in initial block of partition) means that the driver is not able to handle partition boundaries in the data.
When handiling large files you can use the below setting to optimize large file reads:
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.read.max.concurrency", "128") spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.azure.block.size", "128MB")


And as you mentioned with 980 vCores and 245 executors (assuming 4 vCores per executor), the cluster is configured for a high level of parallelism.
Instead of using repartition(980) (matching the number of cores), repartition based on the size of the dataset.
You can do repartition based on dataset size or desired number of files
df = df.repartition(200)

You can use coalesce to reduce partitions when writing smaller outputs
df = df.coalesce(100)
So using the above you can acheive 128 MB to 1 GB per partition. And you can check partitions with below
 print("Number of partitions:", df.rdd.getNumPartitions())

Results:
Number of partitions: 16

